# Generic list in C# 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm trying to create a generic list using C# and .NET 4.0

`List<var> varlist = new List<var>();`
This code produces the error "The contextual keyword 'var' may only appear in a local variable declaration"

The reason being is because I want to do something like this:

```
List<var> varList = new List<var>(); // Declare the generic list
List<Object1> listObj1;              // List of Object1
List<Object2> listObj2;              // List of Object2

varList = listObj1;                  // Assign the var list to list of Object1

varList = listObj2;                  // Re-assign the var list to the list of Object2
```

Is there any way to do this in C# .NET 4.0?

Comment: use `object` instead of `var`

Comment: When you have a general reference to your list, what do you want to do with it? A `List<T>` has a few base interfaces that you can reference to them as, some are not generic so will allow you to not care about the type, but then you probably don't want to do type-specific things with it.

Comment: Is there any way to do this then? Not using var?

Comment: List<var> wouldn't be just _generic_, it would be _super-generic_. var's type must be __resolvable upon the declaration__ of the variable.

Comment: So if I had a list<object> would I be able to overwrite that?

Comment: it sounds like there's a better solution to the general problem you are trying to solve

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with 'varList'. The answer could be in List<dynamic>, or using generics via List<T>, or some other solution. What you're trying to do with var is not supported.

Comment: No need to overwrite, all things are created object!

Comment: Ok thanks guys. Normally I wouldn't post code that I know wouldn't work but I just wanted to get the general idea out there for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: If you ask a question with more context about where you want to do this, people can probably suggest a good alternative.

Comment: Your idea of a generic container list, where you would assign completely different and unrelated lists seems, as written below, a List<T> job

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want a generic list, then you have to define that generic type somewhere. I'm assuming this is at classlevel:

```
class MyClass<T> {
    List<T> someGenericList = new List<T>();
}
```

Or you use the baseclass for all types:

```
List<object> someGenericList = new List<object>();
```

Or you make it `dynamic` (only use this when you're absolutely sure you need it)

```
List<dynamic> someGenericList = new List<dynamic>();
```

Or lastly: you adapt your design. Typically if you have to define such a high level type of collection, you have options to refactor it in a way that it allows you to use more of the common type. If you want feedback on this then you would have to give more information concerning the context.

Don't forget to read [MSDN: An introduction to C# generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

The reason your code doesn't work is because [`var`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) is a keyword and not a type. It substitutes itself for the actual type of the expression that follows and thus allows you to get right to creating your expression instead of having to explicitly define it first. Therefore in order to use it, there actually has to be an expression that follows it.

Comment: And how does this different from what I wrote, meanwhile my answer get down voted for no apparent reason...

Comment: A generic list is not the same as a list of type `object`. That's just a really vague list.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define method parameters with var because the var part must be resolved at compile-time and the compiler cannot do that. Your best bet is to use:

```
List<dynamic> dynamicList = new List<dynamic>();
```

which, I think, should be resolved during compile time to its equivalent

```
List<object> dynamicList = new List<object>();
```

Then, every time you are accessing the members of the list, in order to use them to do something meaningful, you will have to explicitly cast them to your required type. You have to consider whether it is worth to do so. It would be better if you can either:

1. Use different lists for different types
2. Use a base class with a relevant abstract or virtual method that is being overriden with the expected behavior.

Comment: Unless you intend to explain how to use this, it won't work if we take the OP code verbatim and change it to use this.

Answer (score 0):

Change var to something which is not keyword in C#.
For example

```
 List<object> varlist = new List<object>();
```

Comment: @PatrickHofman  read Jeroen Vannevel answer and explain how it has nothing to do with it... And we post our answers at same time by the way.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `var` being a keyword. `dynamic` is a keyword too.